# mismatching between whole data during splitting data

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I've just been reading up on `train_test_split` and have realized that I'm inadvertently leaking data with my current preprocessing setup due to make history-based function `def create_dataset()` and consequently when I print the plot I see totally 24+6=30 time_stamps instead of 32+8=40 !Is it logic such a that history-based approach for prediction with this split situation? if not, how can I fix it?

```py
Y_train= data_train[index]
data_train = data_train.values
print("data_train size: {}".format(Y_train.shape))
```

```
data_train size: (40, 960)
```

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def create_dataHistory(dataset,data_train,look_back=1):
    dataX,dataY = [],[]
    print("Len:",len(dataset)-look_back-1)

    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), :]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(data_train[i + look_back,  :])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

look_back = 10
trainX,trainY = create_dataHistory(data_train,Y_train, look_back=look_back)

trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(trainX,trainY, test_size=0.2)
print("train size: {}".format(trainX.shape))
print("train Label size: {}".format(trainY.shape))
print("test size: {}".format(testX.shape))
print("test Label size: {}".format(testY.shape))
```

```
Len: 29
train size: (23, 10, 1440)
train Label size: (23, 960)
test size: (6, 10, 1440)
test Label size: (6, 960)
```

Comment: Are you trying to predict on time-series data? Because there's [a special function for that](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html)

Comment: @G.Anderson yes sir! but as you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/pu58bkN.jpg) in my data each row reperestes one time stamps which contains 1440 columns or features. So do you think can I use properly for my case with `TimeSeriesSplit`. if so , would you form your answer for me by leaving snippet. you can check my [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YgbhwIgnW42bwOnaxM2e_JHwsf3Q9O2_/view?usp=sharing).